# How to install two instances of the same app on iOS?

Tags: ios

For apps that require me to log in with a user account but don't support multiple accounts per instance, for example instagram, discord, messenger, it would be handy to have more than one of them installed at a time.

How can I do that?

Comment: A microsecond Google Search Experience® found [this](https://wethegeek.com/how-to-duplicate-apps-on-iphone-without-jailbreak/) and [this](https://blogs.innovanathinklabs.com/best-ios-app-cloners-to-duplicate-apps-iphone-without-jailbreak/) and [this](https://9to5mac.com/2021/06/08/you-can-place-multiple-copies-of-the-same-app-on-your-home-screen-with-ios-15/) ...

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to install two instances of the same app on iOS.

Some services accessed by an app also have a web site with equivalent or at least similar functionality. You might be able to get some of the functionality you require by using the app for one account, and the web site (through Safari) for the other account.